React Build Fails with "Reached Heap Limit" Error in Dockerized Environment*
I'm encountering a "FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed" error during the build process of my ReactJS project within a Dockerized environment.
Environment:

ReactJS application
Ubuntu server with 8GB RAM
Docker deployment with docker-compose

Symptoms:

The error occurs when running docker-compose run --rm node yarn build to build the project for a Nginx web server.

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Initially, a 2GB swapfile was created to address the issue, but the error has re-emerged.
Increasing the old space size limit with --max_old_space_size=1200 in the package.json script has no effect.

Question:

How can I effectively address this memory allocation issue during the React build process within the Docker container?
Are there more sustainable solutions compared to relying on a swapfile?

Additional Information:

package.json:

{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "sass": "^1.66.1"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=1200 build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app"
        ],
        "rules": {
            "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off"
        },
        "env": {
            "es2020": true
        }
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]
}


docker-compose.yml:

version: '3'
     
services:
    
  node:
      container_name: my-project_node
      image: node:16
      working_dir: /var/www/my-project
      volumes:
          - ./../:/var/www/my-project


Full Error Output:

yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts --max_old_space_size=1200 build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme

<--- Last few GCs --->

[35:0x5a7e250]   317458 ms: Mark-sweep 1179.6 (1208.4) -> 1179.0 (1208.1) MB, 36175.4 / 1.0 ms  (average mu = 0.206                                                          , current mu = 0.026) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[35:0x5a7e250]   401410 ms: Mark-sweep 1189.6 (1214.8) -> 1184.5 (1217.3) MB, 83341.8 / 0.8 ms  (average mu = 0.067                                                          , current mu = 0.007) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb090e0 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0xa1b70e  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0xce1a20 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0xce1dc7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/n                                                          ode]
 5: 0xe99435  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0xea90fd v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReaso                                                          n, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0xeabdfe v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal                                                          ::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0xe6d33a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Allocati                                                          onOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x11e61e6 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/lo                                                          cal/bin/node]
10: 0x15d9e59  [/usr/local/bin/node]
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: 1



--max_old_space_size=1200 might still be too low, maybe try increasing to 5000

@Mike But is it really intended that yarn uses that much RAM? What if my future server will only have 4gb?

No, I think the default value is 2048, but 4096 is often used, and even 8192, but it'll be down to you
